Suspend laptop when lid is closed in Ubuntu 24.04
I am using Ubuntu 24.04. How can I ensure that the laptop suspends when the lid is closed? I also installed the Tweaks (gnome-tweaks) tool and in Ubuntu 22.04, it used to give a "Suspend when lid is closed" option in the General section, but in Ubuntu 24.04, there is no such option.

This was sadly removed upstream: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/-/commit/782c881ee8c46a3170d192a47b9070514adbafb2

you can check those settings using Dconf Editor (can be installed by typing dconf on the Ubuntu Store).
After installed, press Super, type dconf and hit Enter to open it. Agree with the warning that will appear the first time, then navigate to:
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-ac-action
Once there, you can check or change the value, and also create a Bookmark to go back to that setting easily. Then navigate to:
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-battery-action
and do the same.
Note that to change the value you have to first turn off the switch Use default value by clicking on it. Then you click the button Custom value and choose the setting that works for you. Test it and post the results here to help the community. Thanks.

Open the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file in a text editor as root, for example:
vi /etc/systemd/logind.conf

If HandleLidSwitch is not set to ignore then change it:
HandleLidSwitch=ignore

Make sure it's not commented out (it is commented out if it is preceded by the symbol #) or add it if it is missing.
Reboot your machine or Restart the systemd daemon (this will log you off) with this command:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind


Won’t that just disable the lid switch? That’s not what the OP is trying to do.

It should be HandleLidSwitch=suspend I guess.
